# The range of Fourier Transform is dense in $c_0(\mathbb Z)$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

There were many questions and answers about "The range of Fourier Transform on $L^1(\mathbb R)$ is dense in $C_0(\mathbb R)$.
Using $C^2_c(\mathbb R)$ is the solution of it.

However, when it comes to $L^1(\mathbb T)$, which means $[-\pi,\pi)$(The equivalence class
of $\mathbb R/{2n\pi}$, the range of Fourier Transform on $L^1(\mathbb T)$ is dense in $c_0(\mathbb Z)$. But, how could I prove it? I think I cannot use the similar way.. Could somebody give me an idea?

Comment: It's the same solution.  Use the Fourier inversion formula on sequences in $c_c(\Bbb{Z})$ - which is the space of all sequences of *finite support*.  Show that the inverse transform (=a finite linear combination of exponentials!) is absolutely integrable on the circle.  The sequences with finite support are dense in in $c_0(\Bbb{Z})$ in the $\sup$-norm.